# On Windows 10 (using cygwin running python GitPython), how to do a git pull?

Tags: python-3.x, git, cygwin, gitpython

With this Python code (using GitPython) (passing 'sqa' as branch):

```
    def git_pull(self, branch_name):
        self.repo.git.checkout(branch_name)
        branch = self.repo.active_branch
        print('Current Branch: [' + branch.name + ']')
        self.repo.git.pull('origin', branch)
```

I get the following error:

```
FatalException: Exiting... Cmd('c:\cygwin\bin\git.exe') failed due to: exit code(1)
  cmdline: c:\cygwin\bin\git.exe pull origin sqa
  stderr: 'C:/cygwin/usr/libexec/git-core/git.exe: error while loading shared libraries: ?: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory'
```

What would be the problem, here, and how would I resolve?

I would expect it to complain about repo access as a ssh key is needed.

Comment: Is git installed?

Comment: Yes, git.exe is installed under c:\cygwin\bin\git.exe

Comment: what about "git pull" from inside the Cygwin terminal ?